# Handling JPA's @Column(unique = true) exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I've searched stackoverflow and tried to catch different exceptions as per the past answers but nothing worked.

My Model class is:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Code works if username doesn't exists yet.
But whenever user tries to add a user with a username that already exists in db, it throws exception as `@Column(nullable = false)`. My intention is to catch this error and display "Duplicate username" dialog.
But i am not able to catch it.
This is my method to add user to db:

```
@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
    }  catch (PersistenceException  e) {
        System.out.println("username already exist");
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();

}
```

As mentioned, i've "hit and trial"-ed a lot of exceptions classes but nothing seems to work. It displays following error:

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into User (id, password, username) values (?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.ultranet.servicesImpl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:57)
    at com.ultranet.main.DriverClass.main(DriverClass.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'admint' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 19 more
```

So, how do i catch this exception so that i can display user-friendly message?
P.s: Some of the exceptions i tried catching are:

```
java.sql.SQLException;
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
javax.transaction.RollbackException;
org.hibernate.HibernateException;
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
```

Comment: Have you tried catching org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException and com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException? I thinkhibernate throws org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException to addUser function once the sql exception occurs

Comment: is the value "admint" In field username may be is already existing ?

Answer (score 2):

DB exceptions should always be fatal, that's why they are runtime. From my point of view you should verify yourself if an user with that username already exists before trying to create it. You can then generate a custom exception to be catched by higher code to present to the end user.

Comment: As you see yourself it is quite touchy. You really should test existence with a select User u from User wher u.username=..... and if the result has elements throw your exception. If you try to catch exceptions you will be dependant on either spring or hibernate... which is not good

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the "unique=true" annotation will not help you during runtime. It describes how the database schema should look like. Schema mappers read this annotation and make sure that the column will be unique.

In your case, you tried to insert invalid data and you got an "MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException". It is not easy to extract more details about the problem. Anyways, the persist has failed and puts your current persistence context in a failure / rollback state. Usually, you don't want to end up here.

It is good practice to add a validation step to avoid this completely. Query the database for this username - and if it already exists, show the validation problem. If there would be two processes trying to insert the same username at the same time, you would still run into the initial problem, but chances are very low if you do the validation JUST before persisting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your catching function work well, but the problem is `commit` after that:

`session.getTransaction().commit();`

You should rollback this transaction in your catch block, but not commit out of that.

You can check which line of your code throw that exception. In you err log, it says it is `UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:57)`.